# Modelica - Specify simulation default parameters

Tags: parameters, simulation, modelica

I know I can change `File_init.txt`'s definitions, but I was wondering if there is some way to do it in the class file (.mo) or in a directive to the comiler (omc).

In an attempt to alleviate myself of the [lack of a 'has-a' relationship in Modelica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307788/modelica-join-connectors-after-some-distance), I am writing a Perl wrapper that writes the highest level of my Modelica simulation (with my `has-a`'s turned into `if` and `when` statements) and the compiles (`omc +s` then `make`) and simulates. This would work perfectly if I could specify such parameters as `stop`, `step`, `outputFormat` in some other way, rather than having to open the init file and do a regexp replace on them which is really clunky.

Long story short, is there some directive like the (pseudo-code) example below?

```
class MainSim
  extends BaseSim;
  ...
  simulation.stop = 1E-9;
  simulation.step = 1E-12;
  simulation.outputFormat = "csv";
  ...
equation
  ...
end MainSim;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost Joel, the correct way would be:

`model Model annotation( experiment( StopTime=6.28 ) ); ... end Model;`

You can also have at "example" models (normally placed in a `.Examples` subpackage) from the Modelica Standard Library. They all should have that annotation in place (and if not feel free to [report it](https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/newticket) :)).

Comment: This seems to be correct. I am having some problems making this work with `omc`, however that may be a problem with `omc` (which is still in development), rather than the Spec. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how OMC handles this, but there are standard annotations for experiment parameters.  You can find the information in Section 17.7 of the specification (version 3.2).

Take a look at that and let me know if that addresses your question.

Comment: So you would do something like `model Model annotation( experiment( stop=6.28 ) ); ... end Model;` where Model is your top-level model?